# Difference between read.csv() and read.csv2() in R

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

In R , what is the difference between read.csv() and read.csv2()

The official documentation says,

> In various European locales, as the comma character serves as the
>   decimal point, the function read.csv2 should be used instead

What does this mean. I don't see any difference at the superficial level. Can anybody give out a concrete example to clarify it further.

Comment: The reason I am asking this question is I am confused which one to use

Comment: That depends. Look at file you are trying to read, how the values are separated?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

They are (almost) the same functions - `read.table`. The only difference is default parameters. Look at source code:

```
> read.csv
function (file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", dec = ".", 
    fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...) 
read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
    dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
<bytecode: 0x5e3fa88>
<environment: namespace:utils>
> read.csv2
function (file, header = TRUE, sep = ";", quote = "\"", dec = ",", 
    fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...) 
read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
    dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
<bytecode: 0x5c0a330>
<environment: namespace:utils>
```

From doc (see `?read.table`):

`read.csv` and `read.csv2` are identical to `read.table` except for the defaults. They are intended for reading ‘comma separated value’ files (‘.csv’) or (read.csv2) the variant used in countries that use a comma as decimal point and a semicolon as field separator.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I was not looking at the source code so far.

Comment: It's possible to have comma be both the field separator `sep = ","` and also the decimal-separator `dec = ","`. But of course such fields will be quoted by the csv reader and writer. Anyway, such a file will still be 'real' csv (comma-separated).