# R: Cannot create a formula from a zero-column data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I´m trying to do redundancy analysis (RDA) on my data in R. The  data frame I´m using was uploaded as a Microsoft Excel csv file. The data frame looks something like this:

```
site biomass index

1     0.001 1.5

2    0.122  2.3

3    0.255  4.9
```

When trying to create a formula for the RDA, I constantly get the following message: "Error in formula.data.frame(object, env = baseenv()) : 
  cannot create a formula from a zero-column data frame"

Does anyone know how I can change my data frame so that I no longer get this error message?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share instead the `dput()` of your data?

Comment: Error in formula.data.frame(object, env = baseenv()) - Seems like it has nothing to do with RDA , the problem is with your data

Comment: Hi erasmortg, thanks for your answer. This appeared when I did the dput() on my data: 

> dput(env)
structure(list(), .Names = character(0), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Tr.1-1m;0.300233333;0.5", 
"Tr.1-4m;0.107733333;0.5", "Tr.2-1m;0.0195;0.923", "Tr.2-10m;0.150866667;0.5", 
"Tr.3-1m;0.099733333;0.857", "Tr.3-9m;0.0576;0.5", "Tr.4-1m;0.057433333;0.125", 
"Tr.4-9m;0.064066667;0.375", "Tr.5-1m;0.130466667;0.2", "Tr.5-10m;0.2125;0.66"
))

Comment: structure(list() -  - data.frame is empty.
Show how you download your data

Comment: Hi Rina, I was using:  <- read.csv("data.csv", row.names=1) to import my data into R.

Comment: try <- read.csv("data.csv", row.names=FALSE, sep=';')

Comment: I tried what you suggested and this error messaged showed up: 

<-read.csv("data.csv", row.names=FALSE, sep=';') 
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : invalid 'row.names' specification

There has to be something wrong with the way I´m setting up my data prior to importing.

Comment: Please paste the first few rows of the csv file into the question

Answer (score 0):

You load all your data to row.names instead of columns

1. you used default separator ',' while your data is separated by
   ';'
2. you specified `row.names = 1` so that first column (and the
   only one as the separator is wrong) goes to row.names.

that's why your data.frame has no columns. To fix this, use

```
read.csv('data.csv', sep = ';', row.names=NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :) Thanks for the your answers. I tried the suggestions but what ended up working was to import the data with the <- read.csv2("data.csv", row.names=1), so basically to use  read.csv2 instead of read.csv, as it seems to be used in many European locales.

There is more info on the difference between csv and csv2 here: [Difference between read.csv() and read.csv2() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970091/difference-between-read-csv-and-read-csv2-in-r)