# Remove special characters and placing the data which is in rows as column values

Tags: r

I have data set in which fist row data is with special characters supposed to be the column names, which is in single excel cell, how can I divide those and place it as each column names with R?

Second, third rows data with special characters were supposed to be column values, however placed in rows, how to remove those special characters and replace as column values with R?

Below is the data set for your reference:

```
Row1:age;"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y"
Row2:58;"management";"married";"tertiary";"no";2143;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";261;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
Row3:44;"technician";"single";"secondary";"no";29;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";151;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
Row4:33;"entrepreneur";"married";"secondary";"no";2;"yes";"yes";"unknown";5;"may";76;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
.
.
.
.
```

In total, I have 45,212 rows  .

Comment: Is "Row1:" and so on part of your actual data? If not, have you tried `read.delim`?

Comment: Maybe try [read.csv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970091/difference-between-read-csv-and-read-csv2-in-r). What do you mean by "special characters"?

Comment: Put it in a text document, use `read.table` with `header = TRUE` and `sep = ";"`.

Comment: appreciate your assistance, i tried read.csv2 and got it ,